# Can't find model 'en_core'

Tags: python, pycharm, spacy

I am a newcomer in Python. I run Python 3.7 from PyCharm on Windows 10 and spacy 3.0.0a0 (however when I open spacy in settings/project interpreter, it gives me version 2.3.2). When trying to run the following code

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core', parse=True, tag=True, entity=True)
```

I receive error

```
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core'.
```

It doesn't seem to be a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.

I have seen relevant questions but they did not answer my problem

Comment: Does it exist? Is it `en_core_web_*` family of models you are targeting at? E.g. `en_core_web_md`? If so, try downloading it first with `spacy download en_core_web_md` and then load it.

Comment: `en_core` is not  a spaCy model. Try `nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")`

Comment: Thanks for replying. How can I check if it exists? How can I download en_core_web_md from pyCharm?

Answer (score 1):

You should download the correct model for Spacy!

```
python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_md
```

(or en_core_web_sm, en_core_web_lg)
Then you can use it within python.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
doc = nlp("Work on this!")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that when I type in a cmd window "python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_md", I receive the message 'No compatible models found for v3.0.0 of spaCy'. Same message for en_core_web_sm, en_core_web_lg.